# Interacting with a ViewController that has Multiple child ViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a parent viewController and a child viewController. The childViewController is like a card and functions similar to Apple's stock or map app. I can expand or collapse it and interact with the buttons within it. The only problem is that I can't interact with any buttons within the parent viewController. Anyone know what's the problem.

[image]

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

enum CardState {
    case expanded
    case collapsed
}

var cardViewController: CardViewController!
var visualEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!

lazy var deviceCardHeight: CGFloat = view.frame.height - (view.frame.height / 6)
lazy var cardHeight: CGFloat = deviceCardHeight
let cardHandleAreaHeight: CGFloat = 65

var cardVisible = false
var nextState: CardState {
    return cardVisible ? .collapsed : .expanded
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupCard() 
}

@IBAction func expandCard(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Button Pressed")
}
func setupCard() {

    cardViewController = CardViewController(nibName: "CardViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.addChild(cardViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(cardViewController.view)

    //Set up frame of cardView
    cardViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - cardHandleAreaHeight, width: view.frame.width, height: cardHeight)

    cardViewController.view.clipsToBounds = true

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleCardTap(recognizer:)))
         cardViewController.handleArea.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

}

@objc func handleCardTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .ended:
        animationTransitionIfNeeded(state: nextState, duration: 0.9)
    default:
        break
    }
}

 func animationTransitionIfNeeded(state: CardState, duration: TimeInterval) {
    if runningAnimations.isEmpty {
        let frameAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, dampingRatio: 1) {
            switch state {
            case .expanded:
                self.cardViewController.view.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - self.cardHeight
            case .collapsed:
                self.cardViewController.view.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - self.cardHandleAreaHeight
            }
        }

        frameAnimator.addCompletion { _ in
            //if true set to false, if false set to true
            self.cardVisible = !self.cardVisible
            self.runningAnimations.removeAll()
        }

        frameAnimator.startAnimation()
        runningAnimations.append(frameAnimator)

        let cornerRadiusAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, curve: .linear) {
            switch state {
            case .expanded:
                self.cardViewController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 12
            case .collapsed:
                self.cardViewController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0
            }
        }

        cornerRadiusAnimator.startAnimation()
        }
     }
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have for the view controllers?  There's too little information here to know what's going on.  For example, how are you expanding and collapsing the child view controller's view?  Does the button shown belong to the child, or to the parent?

Comment: The button belongs to the parent. Also, I added the code

Answer (score 1):

'Can't interact' should mean that you can't press. If that is the case the most likely cause is that the button is covered with something (it could be transparent so ensure when testing that there is no transparent backgrounds until you resolve this). The other possible reason would be that you have set some property of the button that would cause this behavior, but you would probably know that so it is almost certainly the former.

Comment: can you check my code. I just edited in the code. The button should return "Button Pressed"

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. This code should work perfectly. The reason why it didn't before was because I added in a visualEffectView. It was covering the parent.